# How do I get rid of the http error when I try to cml send comment

Tags: yaml, github-actions, mlops, cml

this is the .yaml I'm using to run and output a comment with cml

```
name: CNN
on: [push]
jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
    - uses: iterative/setup-cml@v1
    - name: Train model
    env:
      REPO_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r require.txt
        ipynb-py-convert CNN.ipynb CNN.py
        python CNN.py 
        
        #echo "## Metrics"
        #cat metrics.txt
        
        echo "## Metrics" >> report.md
        #cat metrics.txt >> report.md
        
        #echo "## CM" >> report.md
        #cml publish cm.png --md >> report.md
        
        cml send-comment report.md
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRuy5.png) is the error that I get every time I commit with cml send comment uncommented. I've tried many different angles but I can't seem to find a solution

Comment: Please copy/paste error messages instead of linking/screenshots. This helps people with the same problem in the future to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a while ago, but I ran into the same issue recently, and the solution I found might help someone else.

In my case, the issue was related to the workflow permissions on my repo.
To change that, you can follow the steps:

- On GitHub.com, navigate to the main page of your repository.
- Under your repository name, click **Settings**. If you cannot see the "Settings" tab, select the dropdown menu, then click Settings.
- In the left sidebar, click  **Actions**, then click **General**.
- Under **Workflow permissions**, choose **read and write permissions** to the GITHUB_TOKEN to have read and write access for all scopes. Then save it.
  [image]

After that, you should be good to rerun the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Does the workflow have [write access](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) to the repository?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).